# Django assert that response contains one of a list of possible strings

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-tests

I'm writing tests for my Django app using the built-in testing tools. Right now I'm trying to write a test for a page that displays a list of a user's followers. When a user has no followers the page displays a message randomly picked from a list of strings. As an example:

```
NO_FOLLOWERS_MESSAGES = [
    "You don't have any followers.", 
    "Sargent Dan, you ain't got no followers!"
]
```

So now I want to write a test that asserts that the response contains one of those strings. If I was only using one string, I could just use `self.assertContains(request, "You don't have any followers.")` but I'm stuck on how to write the test with multiple possible outcomes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if not any([x in response.content for x in NO_FOLLOWERS_MESSAGES]):
        raise AssertionError("Did not match any of the messages in the request")
```

About `any()`:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work?

```
found_quip = [quip in response.content for quip in NO_FOLLOWERS_MESSAGES]
self.assertTrue(any(found_quip))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Internally](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L379) `assertContains()`, uses the count from `_assert_contains()`

So if you want to preserve exactly the same behavior as `assertContains()`, and given that the [implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/testcases.py#L347) of `_assert_contains()` isn't a trivial one, you can get inspiration from the source code above and adapt one for your needs

### Our assertContainsAny() inspired by assertContains()

```
def assertContainsAny(self, response, texts, status_code=200,
                      msg_prefix='', html=False):

    total_count = 0
    for text in texts:
        text_repr, real_count, msg_prefix = self._assert_contains(response, text, status_code, msg_prefix, html)
        total_count += real_count

    self.assertTrue(total_count != 0, "None of the text options were found in the response")
```

Use by passing the argument `texts` as a list, e.g.

```
self.assertContainsAny(response, NO_FOLLOWERS_MESSAGES)
```